# ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest fails with PublishThemeRequest

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to write a powershell script to publish a theme in my on-premise installation of Dynamics CRM.
According to [this page](https://aylwinwong.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/automatically-change-dynamics-365-theme-using-power-shell/) it should be really straight forward, I create an object of type [PublishThemeRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.publishthemerequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) which derives from [OrganizationRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) and call the method [ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.executecrmorganizationrequest?view=dynamics-xrmtooling-ce-9).

This is the code I'm running:

```
    Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector

    $orgName = "<my organization name>";
    $serverUrl = "http://server_url";
    $Cred = Get-Credential -UserName "<my username>" -Message "Please Enter admin credentials for CRM"
    $conn = Get-CrmConnection -Credential $Cred -OrganizationName $orgName -ServerUrl $serverUrl

    $req = New-Object Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeRequest
    $req.Target = New-CrmEntityReference -EntityLogicalName "theme" -Id "DB80D57A-6410-4D11-B784-0093122802AC"
    $result = [Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeResponse]$conn.ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest($req, $null)
```

This is what I get when I execute the code above:

> Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeRequest", for "ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest" to type 
>   "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationRequest": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeRequest" value of type 
>   "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeRequest" to type "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationRequest"."
>   At C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\Desktop\PublishTheme.ps1:21 char:1
>   + $result = [Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.PublishThemeResponse]$conn.Exec ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

I have been reading the documentation and other websites for a couple of hours now but seem to have hit a wall.
Any ideas of what my problem might be?

Comment: [Strong typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115643/is-powershell-a-strongly-typed-language) might help you understand the problem. I'm guessing you don't understand the cast you are doing at the end in [] brackets.

Comment: What's your CRM on-prem version?